# Perl script for extracting data from a text file

Tags: perl

This is the data in my `music.txt` file

```
Seamus McGuire:The Wishing Tree:09-14-2000:14.95
Pat Kilbride:Loose Cannon:07-02-2000:15.95
Kevin Crawford:Seasons of Mists:06-23-2000:16.95
Prince:Purple Rain:01-01-1995:3.95
Meat Loaf:Bat out of Jell:03-03-1980:11.95
Eddie Money:Two Tickets:09-04-1979:8.98
```

I am trying to write a Unix Perl script that

1. Asks for artist's name (either first or last) from user
2. Displays artist's full name, CD title, date, and price in formatted
   output.
3. Proper heading, with commands of your choice, is expected

can someone help me?

Comment: What do you need help with? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Writing a Perl script sounds like a good idea. What has it got to do with Unix?!

Comment: The way this question is phrased, it seems certain that this is a homework assignment. If we were to write a solution for you then ou would have learned nothing, and in any case that isn't how Stack Overflow is supposed to work. Please do your best to write a program, and if you get stuck on anything *then* come back and ask for help.

Comment: this is not a home work question, I am trying to solve some exercice problems

Comment: i know to write script in shell but perl is new to me

Comment: i need to know how can i take a name and match it with the other file?

Comment: I love the *is expected*. ^^ By whom?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Enter first or last name of artist: "; 
chomp(my $input = <STDIN>); #Take input from user
open (my $fh, "<", "music.txt") or die $!; #Open the file in read mode
while(chomp(my $line = <$fh>)){
        if($line =~ /$input/){ #Check if input matches with line 
                my @artist_info = split/:/,$line; #Split the data from line based on `:`
                print " Name: $artist_info[0]\n CD Title: $artist_info[1]\n Date: $artist_info[2]\n Price: $artist_info[3]\n";
        }
}
close($fh);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/h75av8)